# C cast literal char '0' to int 0 (zero), how?

Tags: c, casting, char, int, type-conversion

How would I go to cast/convert literal `char '0'` to `int 0`?

i.e.:

```
char string[] = "0101";
char ch = string[0];
x = magic(ch);
if (x)
    printf("int zero")
```

Comment: Um... Is "char '0'" the *only* thing you need to convert? What about any other char values?

Comment: There was comment about 48 at some point here. Would like to know more about that approach.

Comment: 48 works in ascii but not ebcdic. @Scott Hunters answer below s/b portable.

Comment: @AnT the idea is to map that `string` to a bit array.

Comment: @KcFnMi: That probably means you need to convert `'0'` to `0` and `'1'` to `1`. Worth mentioning that second part, if that's the case.

Comment: Should I do `if (ch == '0') x = 0 else x = 1;`? Is there a shorter way to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ch = 0;
```

Now, if you want to convert *any* digit-character to its numeric equivalent, you'd need something like:

```
ch = ch - '0';
```